# Rellich–Kondrachov theorem for traces

Tags: sobolev-spaces, compact-operators, trace-map, besov-space

Let $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be the Sobolev space of weakly differentiable functions whose weak derivatives are $p$-integrable, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a domain with Lipschitz boundary. Let furthermore $\gamma$ be the trace map.

I am looking for a theorem that allows me to conclude that $\gamma \colon W^{1,p}(\Omega) \to L^q(\partial \Omega)$ is compact whenever $q < \frac{(n-1)p}{n-p}$, thus e.g. for every $q < 4$ when $p = 2$ and $n = 3$.

(Necas, p103) has such a theorem in the necessary generality. I find the proof not very accessible, however. Another proof that I am aware of
(Demengel/Demengel, p167) makes stronger assumptions on the regularity of the boundary ($C^1$ rather than $C^{0,1}$). **Q1**: *Is such a theorem proved somewhere else in the same generality? Which source would you cite for said result?*

Few books bother with the case of such embeddings as far as I can tell, most only consider embeddings of the type $W^{k,p}(\Omega) \to L^q(\Omega)$. **Q2**: *Is that because the situation I am interested in is treated in the more general context of Besov spaces (which I am not familiar with) instead?*

I have collected some more references for theorems of the Rellich-Kondrachov type [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem#An_overview).

References:

Necas, Jindrich - Direct Methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations.

Demengel, Françoise; Demengel, Gilbert - Functional spaces for the theory of elliptic partial differential equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An even more general form of the result can be found in section 7 of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2009-137-12/S0002-9939-09-10045-X/): the result applies to Sobolev extension domains (which include Lipschitz domains) and the measure on the boundary is not necessarily the surface measure. This short paper is not self-contained: some of the heavy lifting is done in other sources such as [Function spaces and potential theory](http://books.google.com/books/about/Function_Spaces_and_Potential_Theory.html?id=KmyomBiXc-4C) by Adams and Hedberg (an expensive book, unfortunately). But it does a good job of putting the results together, and outlining two ways of obtaining the desired trace theorem: with and without Besov spaces.

*Warning:* if you plan to investigate this subject in any depth, you will not avoid (a) Besov spaces and (b) proofs that are not very accessible. They come with the territory.

*Terminological remark:* I never saw compact *trace* theorems being named after Rellich and Kondrachov. Their names are normally attached to compact *embedding* theorems between function spaces on the same domain.

Comment: Thank you; I'll have to read up on a couple of things to understand that paper. The generalisation on the domain is certainly welcome. As for the name of the theorem: Once one identifies $\gamma(W^{1,p}(\Omega))$ with $W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)$, the question of compactness of $\gamma$ becomes a question of the compactness of the embedding $W^{1-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega) \to L^q(\partial \Omega)$. In this sense, the theorem is of Rellich-Kondrachov type, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: That's a very nice paper.