# Compactness of the trace operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, compact-operators

> Is it true that for a set $\Omega$ with Lipschitz boundary the trace operator $T : H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$ is compact? Can you please give a reference?

I found a theorem in Necas' *Direct methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations*, which says that if $1<p<N, \ 1 \geq 1/q > 1/p-[1/(N-1)](p-1)/p$ then $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ injects compactly into $L^q(\partial \Omega)$.

Unfortunately, a case which interests me is $p=q=2$ and $N=2$, which does not seem to fit in the above result. Can you please provide a reference for this case?

Comment: Duplicate of [Compact embedding into boundary](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1447788#1450585)

Answer (score 2):

It does seem to fit in the above result, since $H^1 \subset W^{1,2-\varepsilon}$. It is better since if $p>2$, it is Holder continuous.